# Single Thread.interrupt() interrupts more than once

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

I created `MyTask` which has 3 things to do inside `run()`. I try to `interrupt()` the thread which holds `MyTask` instance. Unfortunately once it is interrupted, it ends and only string `First task` is printed on the console.

```
public class MyTask implements Runnable {
    private volatile Thread thread;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!thread.isInterrupted()) {
            System.out.println("First task");
        }
        while (!thread.isInterrupted()) {
            System.out.println("Second task");
        }
        while (!thread.isInterrupted()) {
            System.out.println("Third task");
        }
    }

    public Thread start(){
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        return thread;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t = new MyTask().start();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        t.interrupt();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        t.interrupt();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        t.interrupt();
    }

}
```

If I add `Thread.sleep(10)` in the `run()` it starts to **work correctly** and it prints `First task`, `Second task` and finally `Third task` on the console.

The question is: Whydoes  `Thread.interrupts()` work correctly only if I add `sleep()`?

```
public class MyTask implements Runnable {
    private volatile Thread thread;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!thread.isInterrupted()) {
            System.out.println("First task");
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        while (!thread.isInterrupted()) {
            System.out.println("Second task");
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        while (!thread.isInterrupted()) {
            System.out.println("Third task");
        }
    }

    public Thread start(){
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        return thread;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t = new MyTask().start();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        t.interrupt();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        t.interrupt();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        t.interrupt();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote from [Interrupts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html):

> When a thread checks for an interrupt by invoking the static method Thread.interrupted, interrupt status is cleared. The non-static isInterrupted method, which is used by one thread to query the interrupt status of another, does not change the interrupt status flag.

Meaning: Change your code from `thread.isInterrupted()` to `Thread.interrupted()` and try again.

The `sleep()` in between your loops will clear that flag as well by throwing `InterruptedException` immediately (as the current Thread *has been* interrupted)

Comment: you want to say thread.isInterrupted() to Thread.interrupted()

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Javadoc on `Thread.sleep(long)`

> Throws: InterruptedException - if any thread has interrupted the current thread. *The interrupted status of the current thread is cleared* when this exception is thrown.

Hence, adding that `sleep` as well catching (and ingoring) any exception will result in the observed behavior.

Example:

Without the `sleep()`:

- Thread starts with `interrupted = false` thus 1st loop runs
- Thread gets interrupted, i.e. now `interrupted = true`
- 1st loop checks `interrupted` and doesn't run (again)
- 2nd loop checks `interrupted` and doesn't run at all
- 3rd loop checks `interrupted` and doesn't run at all
- finished

With the `sleep()`

1. thread starts with `interrupted = false`
2. loop 1:

   - while condition is checked and body is executed since `interrupted = false`
   - thread gets interrupted, i.e. now `interrupted = true`
   - while condition is checked but this time `interrupted = true` so the loop ends
   - `sleep()` is called and since the thread has been interrupted the exception is thrown and `interrupted = false` again
   - the exception is caught (and ignored) and thus execution is continued normally
3. step 2 is repeated for loops 2 and 3
4. finished